# How to access and sum a value in an array of array

Tags: php, elasticsearch, kibana

Here my data :

```
{
 id: 1
 array1: [
  {
   type: "A",
   value: 20
  },
  {
   type: "B",
   value: 40
  }
 ]
},
{
 id: 2
 array1: [
  {
   type: "A",
   value: 30
  },
  {
   type: "B",
   value: 100
  }
 ]
}
```

What I want to do is to sum the value of array1 where type = A, here the sum would be 20+30 = 50.

I tried to sum the value, but I don't know how to specify only on type A.
How can I do that ? Thank for your help :)

Comment: can you share your query, so that we can build on top of it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) along with [sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html), to achieve your use case

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "array1": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size":0,
   "aggs": {
      "nested_agg": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "array1"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "filtered_agg": {
               "filter": {
                  "term": {
                     "array1.type.keyword": "A"
                  }
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "my_agg": {
                     "sum": {
                        "field": "array1.value"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "nested_agg": {
      "doc_count": 4,
      "filtered_agg": {
        "doc_count": 2,
        "my_agg": {
          "value": 50.0
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works :) so to access to value, we always have to do a nested ?

Comment: @pham01 you cannot query each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you need to be able to do this then you should use the nested datatype instead of the object data type.

Comment: @pham01 thank u for accepting my answer, can you please upvote the answer as well :)